# Retag the "Regxe" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

I'm unable to see whether there is any discussion or plans around submitting tags for clean-up (i.e. flag for improvement / rep-based authority), so I'm going to submit a few requests to tidy up the long tail of probably-mistyped tags.

Could someone retag [regxe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regxe) to [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex)? As it has never been used I'm assuming it was one person's typo.